# what do you call someone who keeps telling you of a favor he did for you

Tags: word-choice

Can not think what word would describe the act of someone who did you a favor and then he keeps mentioning it many times.

Comment: [**Hold it over your head**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hold%20it%20over%20your%20head): This term is for when you do a favor for someone,then use that favor to to taunt or guilt them..